# Java: Redefinir toString() para formatear fecha usando LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date

He estado mirando preguntas parecidas a esta, pero no doy con la tecla. Espero que podáis ayudarme.

En un ejercicio se me pide que redefina el metodo toString() para que LocalDateTime aparezca así:

**2020/01/17T01:57:22.579**

...en lugar de así...

**2020-01-17T01:57:22.579**

Lo he intentado de varias formas. Principalmente de dos:

```
public String getFecha(){
    return fecha.toString();
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return("YYYY/MM/ddEHH:mm:ss.SSS");
}
```

Y también así...

```
public String getFecha(){
    return fecha.toString();
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/ddEHH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String resultado = fecha.format(dtf);
    return(resultado);
}
```

Pero no logro ningún cambio en cómo se muestra la fecha.
Muchas gracias!

EDITO: Tras las dos primeras respuestas que he tenido, y que agradezco enormemente, he seguido probando y sigo sin conseguir obtener el formato de fecha deseado: Me sigue saliendo por defecto.

Por todo esto, he decidido editar y poner todo el codigo que tengo en la clase, a ver si el problema está en otro sitio.

```
package a_basico;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Movimiento {
    private LocalDateTime fecha;
    private final String dni;
    private final double cantidad;
    private final String descripcion;

    public Movimiento(double montante, LocalDateTime hoy, String dniOp, String descr){
        this.fecha = hoy;
        this.dni = dniOp;
        this.cantidad = montante;
        this.descripcion = descr;
    }
    public Movimiento(double montante, String dniOp, String descr){
        this.fecha = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.dni = dniOp;
        this.cantidad = montante;
        this.descripcion = descr;
    }
    public double getCantidad(){
        return cantidad;
    }
    public String getFecha(){
        return fecha.toString();
    }
    public String getDescr(){
        return descripcion;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String str = this.fecha.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/ddEHH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        return str;
    }
    /*
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String resultado = fecha.toString().replace('-', '/');
        return resultado;
    }
    */

    /*
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/ddEHH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String resultado = fecha.format(dtf);
        return(resultado);
    }
    */
    /*
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "YYYY/MM/ddEHH:mm:ss.SSS";
    }
    */
    /*
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String resultado = fecha.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/ddEHH:mm:ss.SSS"));
        return resultado;
    }
    */


}
```

Al final, comentados, he ido dejando todos mis intentos fallidos.

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: En todas sale así :2020-01-17T01:57:22.579? en lugar de salir con la barra?

Comment: Si, en todos mis intentos. Por eso, y viendo vuestras respuestas he llegado a la coclusion de que mi error debe estar en otro sitio.

Comment: He añadido otra opción a la respuesta que he escrito hace un rato, toString cuando son objetos usualmente se utiliza para devolver la información completa del objeto, no para formatear una variable, de todas maneras he escrito de nuevo el método para que devuelva toda la info, más la fecha formateada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado algunos de tus intentos y todos me han dado un resultado similar al esperado, pero con un pequeño problema en el formato, tal que así:

> 2020/01/17vie11:29:05.365

Por lo mismo he cambiado el formato a:

```
yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Y el resultado es :

> 2020/01/17T11:31:14.035

El método `toString()` lo he sobrescrito similar a uno de tus intentos.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String resultado = this.fecha.format(dtf);
    return(resultado);
}
```

He ocupado la clase `Movimiento` que haz compartido y he creado el objeto `movi` y llamado al método `toString()` de esta manera:

```java
Movimiento movi = new Movimiento(2.3, LocalDateTime.now(), "Ejemplo", "prueba" );
System.out.println(movi.toString());
```

Resultado en el IDE (me encuentro utilizando NetBeans):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual manera ha servido en un [compilador online](https://repl.it/@Riaven/FormtatoFecha)

**EDIT:**

Al llamar al método `getFecha()`, se obtiene el formato de manera incorrecta, como tu mencionas, ya que estás haciendo el llamado al `toString()` que posee `LocalDateTime`

> 2020/01/17T12:08:58.149 - Con movi.toString()
>
> 2020-01-17T12:08:58.149 - con movi.getFecha()

Podrías hacer el método getFecha() así:

```
public String getFecha(){
        return this.toString(); //llamando directamente al método
}
```

Aunque `toString()` al ser el método de la clase `Movimiento` debería devolver la información completa del objeto:

```java
@Override
    public String toString(){
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String fechaFormateada = this.fecha.format(dtf);
        return " Fecha : " + fechaFormateada + 
               "\n DNI : " + this.dni + 
               "\n Montante : " + this.cantidad + 
               "\n Descripción : " + this.descripcion;
    }
```

Resultado:

```
 Fecha : 2020/01/17T12:44:41.395
 DNI : Ejemplo
 Montante : 2.3
 Descripción : prueba
```

Comment: Maravilloso!! No sabes cuánto te lo agradezco!! Murcias Garzas!!!

Comment: Me alegro que te ayudara! :) estuve toda la mañana viendo porque no funcionaba hahaha,

Comment: Entonces aun tengo más que agradecerte. Que hayas dedicado tanto tiempo a mi duda es algo que no puedo compensar. Me has ayudado mucho!

Comment: Soy estudiante, este tipo de preguntas me sirven para aprender más :) que tengas un buen día! :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar el metodo replace(oldChar, newChar) para remplazar los caracteres que necesitas.

Algo asi:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;  

public class X {

    private LocalDateTime fecha = LocalDateTime.now();

    public String toString() {
        return fecha.toString().replace('-', '/');
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero lo he intentado de esa manera y sigo como estaba. Creo que al final va a resultar que estoy haciendo algo mal aparte del formato de fecha en si.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede redefinir el método `toString()` de la clase `LocalDateTime`.
La misma está declarada como `final`, y una clase `final` no se puede extender para hacerle la sobrecarga (`@Override`) del método `toString()`.

Lo mas a lo que podes llegar es hacer un wrapper que tenga un `LocalDateTime` como atributo, y hacer un `@Override` del método `toString()` de esa clase wrapper. (Similar a lo que hizo @Iván-Salgado.)

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        MyLocalDateTime mldt = new MyLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(mldt.toString());
     }

     public static class MyLocalDateTime {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime;

        public MyLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
            this.localDateTime = localDateTime;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String rtn = this.localDateTime.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", new Locale("es","AR")));
            return rtn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero lo he intentado de esa manera y sigo como estaba. Creo que al final va a resultar que estoy haciendo algo mal aparte del formato de fecha en si.